# Why Don't These Strings Match?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, if-statement, match

I'm getting the user input like so:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
```

When I compare it like this

```
if(input == "abc"){
  System.out.println("Match!");
}else{
  System.out.println(input + "\nabc");
}
```

---

If I type "abc" I see

> abc
>   abc

Instead of the expected `match`.  What's going on?

Comment: I'd say that's a dupe.  I'm learning Java; moving from JavaScript -- That's a new concept to me.

Comment: Sorry, we can add the `dumb-question` tag

Comment: This question is not dumb. Every rookie makes this mistake. No worries.

Comment: To add onto what @Pshemo said, most beginners make the mistake that Strings in Java are treated as primitives. This is due to the way they are initialized and how operators affect them. I know I was there at one point too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `String` references, not `String` values. Use the `String.equals` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

== is comparing memory locations. you need to use input.equals("abc") instead.